# How to resize Canvas scrollable widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

The idea is that the scrollable canvas and its text widgets grow or fill the entire root/toplevel when I resize it.

I can do this if I work on Frames but for a scrollable frame you need to create a canvas widget and make it scrollable. Now I don't know if the problem is the canvas or the inserted widgets on the canvas?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ScrollableFrame():
    def __init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        self.container = container
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.container, bg="green")
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.container, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scrollable_frame.grid(sticky="wesn")
        self.scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw")
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)
        
        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wesn")
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="wesn")
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(bg="grey20")
    
    s = ScrollableFrame(root)
    
    t = tk.Text(s.scrollable_frame)
    t.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wesn")
    
    t2 = tk.Text(s.scrollable_frame)
    t2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="wesn")

    root.mainloop()
```

I'm glad for help

Comment: Do you mean that the canvas and the scrollbar do not grow to fill the root window when root window is resized?

Comment: @acw1668 Yes, and the text widgets that are inside canvas as well.

Comment: The scrollbar is used to scroll the canvas to view the text widgets, so why do you need to grow/shrink the text widgets?

Comment: The scrollbar isn't an issue.

Comment: My question is *"why do you need to grow/shrink the text widgets"*?

Comment: The goal is that the text widgets resize when I resize root widget.

Comment: If the text widgets are resized when the root window is resized, then what is the purpose of the scrollbar? In this case you don't need scrollable canvas.

Comment: 1. Because this code snippet you see here is just a tiny part of a bigger project. The question is not why I want that, it could be for 1000 reasons. I don't think that I have to explain why. That's why I didn't understand your question "why do you need ...."

Comment: 2. a scrollable frame has nothing to do with my text widget size. It has another reason why it should be scrollable what would take me over 3000 lines of code to explain it

Comment: A scrollbar makes only sense in my opinion when the widget is larger than the screen size which is not the case here. I just want the  content/widget in my case it's a text widget to shrink or grow when I resize root window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on the requirement in the comment, you want to grow/shrink the two text boxes when the root window is resized.  Below is the modified code with the necessary changes to achieve it:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class ScrollableFrame():
    def __init__(self, container, *args, **kwargs):
        self.container = container
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self.container, bg="green")
        self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.container, orient="horizontal", command=self.canvas.xview)
        self.scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(self.canvas)
        self.scrollable_frame.grid(sticky="wesn")
        self.scrollable_frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all")))

        self.canvas.create_window((0, 0), window=self.scrollable_frame, anchor="nw", tags="scrollable")
        self.canvas.configure(xscrollcommand=self.scrollbar.set)

        self.canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wesn")
        self.scrollbar.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="we") # fill horizontally only

        # make self.canvas to fill all the available space of container
        container.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # resize self.scrollable_frame when self.canvas is resized
        self.canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda e: self.canvas.itemconfig("scrollable", width=e.width, height=e.height))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.configure(bg="grey20")

    s = ScrollableFrame(root)

    # make the two text boxes to fill all the space of s.scrollable_frame
    s.scrollable_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    s.scrollable_frame.columnconfigure((0,1), weight=1)

    t = tk.Text(s.scrollable_frame)
    t.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="wesn")

    t2 = tk.Text(s.scrollable_frame)
    t2.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="wesn")

    root.mainloop()
```

So basically the logic is when the root window is resized, the canvas is resized to fill the root window.  Then the frame (`scrollable_frame`) inside the canvas is resized to fill the canvas and finally the two text widgets are resized to fill the `scrollable_frame`.