# How do I create scrollbar on the frame using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

snippets of my codes are attached.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.geometry("1500x900")
root.title("ddw")

frame = tkinter.Frame(root)
#frame.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=20,pady=10)

frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side="left",fill="y")

ls = [(x+1)*5 for x in range(10)]

for x in ls:

    cnn_info_frame = tkinter.LabelFrame(frame, text="cn")
    cnn_info_frame.grid(row=x, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

    vv1_label = tkinter.Label(cnn_info_frame, text="vv1")
    vv1_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
    vv2_label = tkinter.Label(cnn_info_frame, text="vv2")
    vv2_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
    vv3_label = tkinter.Label(cnn_info_frame, text="vv3")
    vv3_label.grid(row=2, column=0)

    vv1_entry = tkinter.Entry(cnn_info_frame)
    vv2_entry = tkinter.Entry(cnn_info_frame)
    vv3_entry = tkinter.Entry(cnn_info_frame)

    vv1_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    vv2_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)
    vv3_entry.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)



root.mainloop()
```

I am really new to tkinter and tech is not my background so any help is most appreciated. I want to create a scroll bar on the left so I added

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame)
scrollbar.pack(side="left",fill="y")
```

but that gives me this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kamathp/PycharmProjects/CFOptimisation/00tkinter_eg4.py", line 20, in <module>
    cnn_info_frame.grid(row=x, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)
  File "C:\Users\kamathp\Anaconda3\envs\PA36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2226, in grid_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!frame which already has slaves managed by pack
```

how do I fix it?
My actually code has a lot of labelFrames button etc, but my main issue not able to add the scroll bar to the left.

Comment: Either changing `scrollbar` to use `grid()` or `cnn_info_frame` to use `pack()`.

Comment: thanks @acw1668. I added  - scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10). I can see the scrollbar but its very small and at the top left, and doesnt look like its working?

Comment: A frame does not support scrolling, so why do you think that the scrollbar works for your case?

Comment: Tkinter has no scrollable Frames but you can make your own with tk.Canvas and add a frame to the canvas. Then you make the canvas scrollable.

Comment: I asked a similar question it might help you [How to resize Canvas scrollable widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67860815/how-to-resize-canvas-scrollable-widget)

Comment: @Module_art thank you that was helpful. I now have that works well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter)

Answer (score 0):

A lean solution, making a new class FrameX, with an option to enable scrollbar (works for LabelFrame too).

```
import tkinter as tk

class FrameX(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root, scrollbar=None, **kwargs):
        if scrollbar=='v':
            # create a local frame to hold the scrollbar
            fr = tk.Frame(root)
            fr.pack(kwargs)
            
            # Create a Scrollbar widget
            bar = tk.Scrollbar(fr)
            bar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

            # create a canvas & config for scrollbar to detect changes in canvas
            canvas = tk.Canvas(fr)
            canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill="both", expand=True)
            canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=bar.set)
            bar.config(command=canvas.yview)

            # initiate Frame with root=canvas
            super().__init__(canvas)
            # self.configure(borderwidth=0) # stick to outer labelframe
            self.pack(padx=0, pady=0) # stick to outer labelframe

            # actually add <self> to the canvas
            canvas.create_window((0,0), window=self, anchor='nw')
            # setup func to change scrollbar to cover the canvas content
            canvas.bind('<Configure>', lambda x: canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox('all')))

        else: # normal frame
            super().__init__(root)
            self.pack(kwargs)


# Create the main Tkinter window
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('600x200')
root.title("Scrollbar in Frame")

lb = FrameX(root, scrollbar='v', expand=True, fill='both', padx=10, pady=20)

for j in range(10):
    bt = tk.Button(lb, text = 'OK', width=10, height=2)
    bt.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

# Run the Tkinter event loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you add those buttons *after the window is shown*, like by clicking a button, then you will find that the scrollbar is not activated because you bind the `<Configure>` event on the wrong widget.  The event should be bound on instance of `FrameX` instead.

Comment: @acw1668, I don't quite understand your comment, did you have problem when trying the code?

Comment: What I mean is that do not add those buttons into `lb` when starting the application.  Create a button in the root window and add those buttons inside the button callback.  Then you will find that the scrollbar will not be activated.